# How do I pass extra context to Pundit scopes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pundit

I have a system where a `User` can be associated with many `Portals`, however a user's permissions may differ between portals.

For example, a user might be able to see unpublished posts in one portal, but not in another portal.

For methods like `show?`, I can grab the portal off the record.

```
def show?
  portal = record.portal
  # logic to check whether, for this particular portal, 
  # this user has permission to view this record
end
```

However that solution doesn't work for policy scopes.

Is there any way I can, say, pass in the portal to `policy_scope` method in the controller?

---

One solution I've seen around the place is to set a (temporary) attribute against the user, so that policy methods can use it. e.g.

```
# model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :current_portal
  ...
end

# controller
posts = portal.posts
current_user.current_portal = current_portal
policy_scope posts

# policy Scope
def resolve
  portal = user.current_portal
  # logic to scope these records by user's portal permissions
end
```

However this seems like a workaround, and I can definitely think of other scenarios where I'd like to be able to give authorisation logic more context as well, and I don't want this workaround to become a bad habit.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What is `logic to scope these records by user's portal permissions`? This information seems quite crucial to your problem. There are a couple of "workarounds" to pass additional context to Pundit, but (from experience) 95% of the time if you feel the need to use them then "you're doing it wrong".

Comment: For example, the [pundit README shows another way of passing additional context, via the `pundit_user` method](https://github.com/varvet/pundit#additional-context), but also clearly says "If you find yourself needing more context than [the current user and domain model], consider whether you are authorizing the right domain model". In other words, the question boils down to: *What resource are you trying to authorize*? (And how does that currently work?)

Comment: "What resource are you trying to authorize?"  The problem isn't with authorizing records. The problem is with authorizing scopes. You're right though, I debated internally on whether to include any of the "logic to scope these records by user's portal permissions". Basically, I have a `PortalUser` join model between portals and users. So my current solution is to set `pundit_user` to the `PortalUser` rather than the `User`. However, this doesn't work for the various levels of admin users who have access to all portals, and don't have portal users themselves.

Comment: By "resource", I did primarily mean a collection of records - i.e. The scope. Although I suspect the solution may impact individual records too. So, my question stands: can you show what the policy scope actually looks like? Maybe even the solution would be to change the definition of `current_user` globally across the whole application??!

Comment: I can only hypothesise without seeing any concrete code.

Answer (score -1):

Pundit authorization classes are plain old ruby classes. Using pundit `authorize` method you can pass an object to be authorized and an optional query. When you for example use authorize method as

```
authorize @product, :update?
```

the authorize method will call the `update?` method on the `ProductPolicy` class. If no query passed, controller action name + ? mark will be set as the query. Take a look at [Pundit authorize method definition](https://github.com/varvet/pundit/blob/57ec8879139a51f94dc9a9a9870bc9824e2c9c8a/lib/pundit.rb#L177-L187).

So for passing extra parameters to Pundit authorize method, you should override authorize method with an extra argument:

```
module Pundit
  def authorize(record, query=nil, options=nil)
    query ||= params[:action].to_s + "?"

    @_pundit_policy_authorized = true

    policy = policy(record)

    if options.nil?
      raise NotAuthorizedError, query: query, record: record, policy: policy unless policy.public_send(query)
    else
      raise NotAuthorizedError, query: query, record: record, policy: policy unless policy.public_send(query, options)
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your policy class you could use this extra param

```
class ProductPolicy
  ...
  def update?(options)
    ...
  end

  def new?
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

As you can see, you can have policy methods that accept an extra options argument.

Then you can use authorize method in your controllers in one of these ways:

```
authorize @product
authorize @product, nil, { owner: User.find(1) }
authorize @product, :some_method?, { owner: User.find(1) }
authorize @product, :some_method?
```

Comment: IMO this is a very ugly workaround. You're changing the definition of `authorize`, which will (in a large rails application) infect 100s of files with a `nil` parameter in all of these method calls. And for what purpose? It's not even clear what problem you're trying to solve here; from experience, almost any real example can be solved without doing this, but I can't demonstrate how to do this without actually seeing the method body of your hypothetical `def update?(options)`.

Comment: @TomLord No it's not required to add nil parameter in every method call. In the line containing `if options.nil?` it checks to send options parameter whenever it's needed. That whenever you use authorize method with options attribute, it expects that method on authorization class to accept one argument.

Comment: @TomLord After all I think it's better to put `options` argument at the end of argument list like `def authorize(record, query, options)` so that you won't have to change any line of your code anywhere. But when using authorize method you should call it in one of these ways: `authorize(@product, nil, extra_param)` or `authorize(@product, :update?, extra_param)`.

Comment: It's required on any method call that also specifies a `query` though, isn't it? Method signatures like: `foo(nil, nil, nil, something_else)` are an anti-pattern; a problem that's usually solved by using named parameters instead. But either way, implementing your solution in a large rails app will - like I said - infect many invocations across other controllers.

Comment: No. Because if you don't send options parameter (if it's nil) it will call authorize method as it was before: without options parameter `raise NotAuthorizedError, query: query, record: record, policy: policy unless policy.public_send(query)`.

Comment: As for your second suggestion above, I like the idea of `authorize(@product, :update?, extra_param)` the most -- but once again I go back to my statement that this should almost never be needed in the first place. This has been a feature request in Pundit many times, and the library author has repeatedly explained/demonstrated why it's not necessary if you just pass a correct domain model to be authorized in the first place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170677/discussion-between-tom-lord-and-aref-aslani).

Comment: I've updated my answer this way: `authorize(resource, query, extra_param)`